# Redesign the default view - the sidebar takes way too much space!

Tags: feature-request, design, homepage

On SO, in the default view (Recent Questions), I've got more than 2 screen heights of *Interesting Tags* and *Ignored Tags*. Followed by 2 screen heights of *Recent Tags* and *Recent Badges*.

The actual questions use only 2 screen heights of space, so I'm left with lots of wasted space.

I recommend removing *Interesting/Ignored Tags* from the front page completely. They should rather be available in a tab in the user menu.

(I did a search but found no similar proposal. If this is a dup, I'd be glad to close, just tell me.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered consolidating your interesting/ignored using wildcards?

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/interesting-and-ignored-tags-now-support-wildcards/

Comment: Thanks, that's a great feature I was not aware of. But I still think the interesting/ignored tags should rather be moved.

Comment: Just applied, and it still takes a lot of room.