# Set Ignored/Interesting tags based on basic regular expressions?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, ignored-tags

On Stack Overflow I have set up around 150 ignored tags. And this list is growing every day. But I still see new questions with tags I want to ignore that are very similar to my ignored ones.

For example, I don't care about SQL. Not at all, not in any context. I'm just not interested.
So I have set up the following ignored tags: sql, sqlserver, sql-server, mysql, sqlite, sqlexpress, sqlserver2005, sqlserver2008, sql-server-2005, postgresql...

Then a new question might come up with the tag 'linq-to-sql' and I think "oh darn I'm gonna have to add that one too". It is really tedious to have to do this all the time (and it fuels my OCD :o)

I would like to add something like `*sql*` as an ignored tag, and that should be the end of it.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5027/redesign-the-default-view-the-sidebar-takes-way-too-much-space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use wildcards as you can see [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/interesting-and-ignored-tags-now-support-wildcards/).

Comment: I thought we could and I tried to do one for "feature*" hoping that it would pick up "feature-request" but it didn't work.

Comment: I take that back, it works for highlighting interesting ones, but clicking on a tag with a wildcard in it will ignore the wildcard when displaying matching questions.

Comment: Blimey I did not see that one coming. Feature already implemented exactly as I requested! Wtf!??! Thanks!

Comment: This was originally raised back in the days of UserVoice -- perhaps it needs to be documented better...